# SetProperty on CngKey always updates the key while Assign permission to machine key. Is this right behaviour?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, pki, cng

SetProperty on CngKey while giving access on machineKey always updates the CngKey. Is this correct behaviour?

I am setting permissions ACL on the CngKey. When permissions are set on the key using SetProperty, it gets updated every time i apply the same permissions.(I should update ideally for different rules/permissions) This is not the behaviour with RSACryptoServiceProvider or CAPI. it doesn't get updated for same rules being applied, but updates when we apply different rules.

Is this correct behaviour?

```
CngProperty permissions = new CngProperty(
    NCRYPT_SECURITY_DESCR_PROPERTY,
    sec.GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(),
    CngPropertyOptions.Persist | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION);

cngKey.SetProperty(permissions);
```

Expected -> CngKey shouldn't be updated (CngKey has a timestamp that gets updated that means key gets updated) for same permissions being applied, but should update on different permissions.

Actual:-> CngKey updates every time when SetProperty gets called.

Comment: What timestamp are you reading?

Comment: The system timestamp..the cngKey gets updates after every setProperty ..system file in crypto/keys. The same behaviour isn't observed with rsaCryptoService provider system key which is in crypto/rsa/ machineKeys. The timestamp as in system time doesn't get updated for CAPI.